# Remove linked images from string

Tags: php, regex, html-parsing, preg-replace

I need some help with a new function which I am developing. The problem is that I don't know how to solve it.

I have an string with HTML code inside and what I want to do is to remove all the images inside which are with a link:

```
$string = "html code html code **<a href=""><img src="" /></a>**";
```

I have been thinking in the use of preg_replace(); but I don't know how could it be the pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$result = preg_replace('/<a href="[^"]*">[^<]*<img src="[^"]*"[^>]*>[^<]*<\/a>/sim', '', $subject);
```